# What is the song played by India throughout the movie?

Tags: soundtrack, stoker

The movie *Stoker* is full of symbolism (it at least feels that way). A few times we observe India playing a song on the piano, and in a pivotal scene, she is joined by her Uncle Charlie.

Because of the deliberate feel of much of the movie, from shooting angles to clothing, it seems logical to deduce that the music is just as deliberate. So: *What is the song played by India?*

Comment: This question has great potential for a proper analysis question based on the music piece, though not pulled through to the end.

Comment: @ChristianRau "What was the significance of the song "Duet" played by India in Stoker?" Along those lines? TBH I think there is a LOT for potential analysis in Stoker.

Comment: Yeah, in addition to (and not just in place of) just identifying the song. Because up until the last sentence (the actual question) you speak much of how important the song might be for the story and its meaning. And it would be a waste of a good question to keep it at simply identifying the piece then.

Comment: I think it may warrant a separate question, though you do make a good case for expanding the question. Hmm...

Comment: Voting to leave this question open. As far as I know, while questions that ask to identify movies and TV shows (and episodes) are off-topic here, there is [*neither* a site policy nor a community consensus to ban *all* questions that involve identifying something about a movie](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4897/1006).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The song is called [Duet by Phillip Glass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tuuxnziJJS4).

From [interview with director](http://film.list.co.uk/article/48293-interview-park-chan-wook-korean-director-on-his-hitchcockian-thriller-stoker/):

> ‘The piano scene was in the original script, but I could immediately see an opportunity for me. Rather than take a written piece of music from an old master, I wanted to do something entirely new, so I approached Phillip Glass.